# how to include external jar file using PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

When I run a mapreduce job using hadoop command, I use -libjars to setup my jar to the cache and the classpath. How to do something like this in PIG?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
register /local/path/to/myJar.jar
```

Comment: FYI this is in your pig script not on the command line - I'm easily confused  =)

Answer (score 19):

There are two ways to add external jars to Pig environment.

1. Use "-Dpig.additional.jars" to start Pig

   `pig -Dpig.additional.jars=/local/path/to/your.jar`
2. Use "register" command in Pig scripts or grunt

   `register /local/path/to/your.jar;`

You can use any one according to your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

An extension to [zsxwing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423990/how-to-include-external-jar-file-using-pig/16162785#16162785)'s answer. 
You can also specify multiple jar paths as

```
pig -Dpig.additional.jars="/local/path/1/*:/local/path/2/*"
```