# Pig Hcatalog error

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to run pig script in local mode on a single node cluster as given below.

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ pig -x local -f "/home/hduser/ddsoft/pigscript/FirstUDF.pig"
```

But I am getting below error.

> [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 101: file
>   '/home/hduser/ddsoft/hive-0.13.1-bin/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hcatalog-core-0.13.1.jar'
>   does not exist.

how do I register the jar file mentioned in the error message. I tried updating the .bashrc, but it didn’t fix the error.

Comment: i found that the jar does exist in /home/hduser/ddsoft/apache-hive-0.13.1-bin/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hive-hcatalog-core-0.13.1.jar. How do i make pig know the change in the jar location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423990/how-to-include-external-jar-file-using-pig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423990/how-to-include-external-jar-file-using-pig)